# Ruby on Rails: How do you create a `has_one` relationship with duplicating primary keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, model-associations

I have 2 Tables:

```
Dogs
- id (primary key)

Cats
- id (primary key)
```

I would like to introduce a third table let's say `Collars`, that both dogs and cats have:

```
Collars:
- id (primary key)
- size
```

Typically if it was just Dog -> Collar model association, I could do a `has_one` relationship, and the default primary key `id` relationship would resolve.

```rb
class Dog < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :collar
end

dog.collar.size = "XL"
```

However, since I have 2 models (dogs and cats), I'm not sure how this association can resolve, since Dog and Cat tables can have duplicate `id` values. So the `has_one` relationship with the primary key falls apart.

```rb
class Dog < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :collar
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :collar
end

# Dog Record - id: 1
# Cat Record - id: 1
# 2 separate tables allow for duplicate primary keys, so it would be impossible to resolve

dog.collar.size = "XL"
cat.collar.size = "S"
```

Is there a way to make this relationship work with active record associations?

Comment: use belongs_to :collar, the collar id will always be unique

Comment: While @dbugger's suggestion is much more logical, you could also look at [Polymorphic Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). This stores the object id and type such that it would be `collarable_id: 1, collarable_type: 'Dog'` and `collarable_id: 1, collarable_type: 'Cat'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dbugger. Ok I think that makes sense. So basically, I would migrate the Dog and Cat databases to have a `collar_id`, to establish the foreign key. And then do a Dog/Cat :belongs_to a Collar relationship. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: As extension to dbuggers solution: If you need the reverse direction (Collar -> Dog/Cat), you can add a method animal in your collar-model: def animal  return dog || cat end

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion:
add size directly to dogs and cats table because it takes less space than a whole new table and less complex

here `belongs_to` can help you